# How Force Linq to Sql classes to use connection string from file

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to put my connection string in a file like .udl, to change connection string from outside project, because i want to put my db to a server.

I use LINQ to SQL Classes and typed dataset, i want those items use a connection string inside a file near the project(like udl), could i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to SQL DataContext has a constructor which accepts a connection string. That connection string is passed on to the provider (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350721.aspx).

You could read the connection string from an arbitrary file and pass it to said constructor when you need to initialize your DataContext object.

Comment: Yep, simple and effective. There is also an overload that takes an open connection, which can be useful for injecting more complex scenarios (for example, using mini-profiler, which exists as an ado.net decorator)